# Facing digital abuse : need advice to severe all digital relationship with ex-boyfriend and secure my computer/phone

Tags: attacks, ddos

My ex-boyfriend broke up with me on October 9th, 2015 and we haven't been together since and we've been friends. He is still super controlling, jealous, verbally abusive, and manipulative even though were not together and I just want to get away from him, but every time, he threatens to recycle my IP address just because I don't want anything to do with him.

He threatens to boot off anyone who wants to talk to me and everything, BUT WE ARE NOT TOGETHER AND WILL NOT BE. I need this to stop, the only way he got this power to DDoS is because he made some friend who taught him and now the powers going to his head I swear.

Comment: Is there a specific question here? We cannot protect you from your boyfriend or a DDoS attack (assuming your boyfriend actually understand what that is). Local police and your ISP are probably more helpful.

Comment: He's a long distance, I'm asking how I prevent a DDos or protect my ip or generate a new one

Comment: Is this your home internet's IP or do you run some kind of public service with a static IP address? In the former case, the address is usually dynamically assigned to you by the ISP from a large pool. There's no way for your ex to take it away and attacking it will quickly get blocked by a competent ISP. You will get a new one each time you restart your router. Also threatening to do cyber attack is illegal in most countries and is worth reporting to the police.

Comment: Alright understood, now once i get that new IP how can i prevent him from getting my new one. The only contact I have with him is through skype and facebook, he met this booter friend of his through skype using some kind of tool and i'm thinking tis best that i delete his contact (already have)

Comment: I think you should solve this in a non IT way and also reinstall you operating system and also don't talk with him since it can get the ip in this way.

Comment: This starts and ends with you making a complaint to the police. He's not your friend if he's controlling, manipulative and threatening you. Make records of any contact he has with you.

Comment: Harassment is a legal matter in most countries, and is usually taken quite seriously. The police should be able to help, but if you're looking for any additional help, there may well be local resources available to you outside the legal framework, who can help you understand your rights and listen to your concerns. As an example, in the UK we have [NDVH](http://www.nationaldomesticviolencehelpline.org.uk/) and a large number of local charities. People often assume that they're only interested in physical abuse, but they're available for anyone in need of help. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Make sure "Advanced | Connection | Allow direct connections to your contacts only" is checked in Skype. See [Skype to hide IP addresses by default, protecting gamers everywhere](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2016/01/skype-to-hide-ip-addresses-by-default-protecting-gamers-everywhere/)

Answer (score 1):

No, DDOS is not simple and not cheap. Most jokers that think they "acquire cheap attacking/spying" tools, will get their computer infected instead.

**The most worrisome part is not DDOS , but [Spyware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyware)** install into your phone and computer when you are not aware. Plug in a mini-usb thumdrive and install spyware doesn't take 5 minutes. Time for taking a bath or using washroom is enough.

IMHO, you should "sanitize" all your internet related equipment, change your phone, computer, WIFI router password. Computer with shared access/password should be wipe clean, phones should reformat to factory setting (just backup all your files and numbers".

If the santization too much for you, you may try install free antivirus(e.g. Avira, Comodo, Malwarebytes , etc.) on your computer and phone and do a full system scan to look for bad stuff.

On the other hand, for digital abuse such as trolling and personal attack over facebook, you can log complain to facebook. But is is easier if you spend little time and make use of "block person/block post from this person", you will never see them appear on the feed again.

For phone chat apps, it will be much tedious but do-able : get yourself a new phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is a website so your IP is only known to their servers. Unless your ex hacked facebook, he cannot get your IP this way.

It used to be possible to get the IP of a Skype user when the client used direct peer-to-peer connection. Microsoft is now proxying all traffic through their servers. However, there are still some Skype resolver websites around that claims can reveal a user's IP. You can probably register a throw-away Skype account and see if any of them actually works. (Do not use your real account as it can get spammed.)

Note there are other ways someone can get your IP address. For example by planting malware on your computer or trick you to visit a website directly under his control, so be extra vigilant with files/links sent by them. If you think any threat is genuine, better contact law enforcement.